# How to investigate or fix performance issues?

Tags: 2010

I am using sharepoint 2010. We have created some webpart where the endusers can search on items. These items are available in 4 lists. The end user can check checkboxes in which lists he would like to search. If he don't check anything there will be searched in all these 4 lists. It is very slow at this moment. How can I investigate or fix performance issues in SharePoint custom webparts?

Here is one of the code which is used to get all items from one of the lists:

```
var query = (from i in spContext.Product.ToList()
                             where !(i.Removed.HasValue && i.Removed.Value)
                             select i
                             );
```

Is this code OK? Or is it better to use CAML query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how many items in the list, if list contains many items i.e more than 5000 items in each list View, then performance issue can occur.

We had the same the issue in the past, where we trying to get the all List Items from list where List have more than million items and list view threshold set at 20000. when ever we run the powershell, it captured the all resource and App Pool hang for everybody else in the web app. Then with the help of MSFT we come to know that when we run the powershell it trying to load all items first then output it. But this is for one list only

in you case you have 4 Lists go throw, so based on total items and threshold you fall in the same category.

another thing how you query the list, may be you need to run query against the index column or MetaData column which are fast than regular column.

did you try to enable the Developer DashBoard to monitor the performance and saw  which part taking too much time?

another 3rd party tool available, you can try 30 days trial may help you.

http://www.sharepointperformance.com/monitor-sharepoint/net-monitoring/

http://www.sharepointboco.com/troubleshooting-performance-issues-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Please site this 5000 item limit degredation issue, lists can have millions of rows, and I'll change my downvote. If you mean 5000 items returned in a view, please state that instead. 5000 items in a list isn't a big deal.

Comment: I m talking about list view threshold not  list items itself...

Comment: Then can you explain how the list view threshold would be an issue when querying a list in the mannor in which he describes? I don't see the relevancy in that aspect of your answer.

Comment: i update the anwser with information...just curious if you ever deal large lists, its took almost 4 months to delete a 35million items list, we used the webservices for it.

Comment: Yes, and they are generally not an issue using CAML to get the items needed.

Comment: yes, i respond his investigation part why this is slow, still vote down. i am ok upto you

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the size of the lists.

If your are querying several thousands of items, then Linq is absolutely horrible performance-wise and you will do well to use CAML queries instead.